# rails 4 how ro remove the limit condition from sqlite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a table for Questions and in the index page i want to show only the Questions of the current user so I do this :

```
Question.find_by_user_id current.id
```

but it only return the 1st record with this id. when i looked in the generated sqlite code I found this

```
SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
```

so I need to remove this limit or make it `nil`

Comment: Just a wild guess try with `where` `Question.where(user_id: :current_user.id)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find_by` always returns a single record matching with given conditions.Instead use `find_all_by` or `where`

```
Question.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
```

**OR**

```
Question.where(user_id: current_user.id)
```

If you are using Rails 4,then i would suggest you to use `where`.

Answer (score 0):

According to rails docs the find_by takes in arguments and passes it to the find_by method.So there is not other way to change the limit provided unless you change the query directly to a where clause.

```
def find_by(*args)
  where(*args).take
end
```

Final Answer
`Question.where(user_id: current.id)`